# Image onclick dialogue box?

Tags: image, onclick

I trying to get an image (cookie policy) that, once clicked, displays a dialog box informing that cookies are used on this website. I was hoping to use a jQuery dialogue box but it seem difficult.

Demo link: http://myfirststepsto.weebly.com/

The jQuery I would like to use: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

```
<div id="oneout">
<span class="onetitle">

</span>
<div id="oneout_inner">
<centre>

<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89687987/mycookie.png"  alt="cookie policy" />
</a>

<br></center></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a fiddle for you hope it helps!  [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YL3DL/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="oneout">
    <span class="onetitle"></span>
    <div id="oneout_inner">
        <center>
            <a><img id="opener" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89687987/mycookie.png"  alt="cookie policy" /></a>
            <br>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```